# Jupyter Notebooks: can I use an SSH connection or terminal-session as my 'kernel'?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I don't have much experience using Jupyter notebooks - but have seen they are valuable for running (say) 'R' or 'Python' code.

I was wondering - can the kernel used by Jupyter notebooks be a terminal or an SSH session connected to a shell? Rather than running a particular language interpreter like Python etc? Is it something people are doing?

Ideally I would want to use a Docker image - so the whole thing can be 'reset' at the end to be replayed?

Comment: There's a bash kernel [here](https://pypi.org/project/bash_kernel/#description). See [here](https://saturncloud.io/blog/how-to-use-bash-commands-in-jupyter-notebook/) or [here](https://note.nkmk.me/en/jupyter-notebook-kernels-bash/) for a walk-through to setting it up and using it. As for reset, you can have a temporary one available via MyBinder, see main repo where the have it set up for that [here](https://github.com/takluyver/bash_kernel). You click 'launch binder' to kick it off. Repo2docker makes a docker image from it and then you can launch it later by pointing the MyBinder service ...

Comment: <continued> at the repo again later. (The first time it builds it for use later. If the image has been lost or the repo updated it will go through the build step again before launching it.) I use the bash kernel in my notebook 'Getting_Circos_Up_and_Running.ipynb' that you can launch on the MyBinder service by starting [here](https://github.com/fomightez/circos-binder) and clicking on 'launch binder'. The install steps there are [postBuild](https://github.com/fomightez/circos-binder/blob/master/postBuild).

Comment: <continued> at the repo again later. (The first time it builds it for use later. If the image has been lost or the repo updated it will go through the build step again before launching it.) I use the bash kernel in my notebook 'Getting_Circos_Up_and_Running.ipynb' that you can launch on the MyBinder service by starting [here](https://github.com/fomightez/circos-binder) and clicking on 'launch binder'. The install steps for the kernel are there are [postBuild configuration file](https://github.com/fomightez/circos-binder/blob/master/postBuild). So Docker is involved but you don't have to ...

Comment: <continued> necessarily maintain yourself an it is way more portable and can be used by anyone. Of course, you could just build installations of the kernel into your Dockerfile the typical way, too.

Comment: Thanks for these comments - I'll take a look.